# ReactNative Expo app wrongly listed details in Play Console

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-permissions, android-orientation

I've uploaded a React Native app built in via Expo. I've set permissions to none:

```
{
  "expo": {
   "android": {
      "permissions": []
      ... other settings
    }
    ... other settings
}
```

And I've set it to portrait mode only:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "orientation": "portrait",
    ... other settings
  }
}
```

But when I upload the app-bundle to the PLayConsole it lists the app with 15 permissions:

> android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>   android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
>   android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE android.permission.INTERNET
>   android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
>   android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
>   android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES android.permission.STORAGE
>   android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
>   android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
>   com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
>   com.sja.firstaid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
>   host.exp.exponent.permission.C2D_MESSAGE

and both orientations under features:

> 2 features: android.hardware.screen.landscape,
>   android.hardware.screen.portrait

I cannot identify a reason for either of these settings to be ignored.

Comment: Can you double check your `manifest`?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Expo appears to be ignoring the [ ] permissions within app.json and instead is creating a manifest populated with the all the permissions listed.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** permissions key appear to ignore permission instead of add permission list [Docs](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/#android)

List of additional permissions the standalone app will request upon installation,
along with the minimum necessary for an Expo app to function.

```
  To use ALL permissions supported by Expo, do not specify the "permissions" key.

  To use ONLY the following minimum necessary permissions and none of the extras supported
  by Expo, set "permissions" to []. The minimum necessary permissions do not require a
  Privacy Policy when uploading to Google Play Store and are:

  • receive data from Internet
  • view network connections
  • full network access
  • change your audio settings
  • draw over other apps
  • prevent device from sleeping

  To use the minimum necessary permissions ALONG with certain additional permissions,
  specify those extras in "permissions", e.g.

  ["CAMERA", "RECORD_AUDIO"]

  ExpoKit: to change the permissions your app requests, you'll need to edit
  AndroidManifest.xml manually. To prevent your app from requesting one of the
  permissions listed below, you'll need to explicitly add it to `AndroidManifest.xml`
  along with a `tools:node="remove"` tag.

"permissions": [
  "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
  "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
  "CAMERA",
  "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS",
  "READ_CONTACTS",
  "READ_CALENDAR",
  "WRITE_CALENDAR",
  "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
  "READ_PHONE_STATE",
  "RECORD_AUDIO",
  "USE_FINGERPRINT",
  "VIBRATE",
  "WAKE_LOCK",
  "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
  "com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT",
  "com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT",
  "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE",
  "com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION",
  "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES",
  "com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS",
  "com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT",
  "com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE",
  "com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ",
  "com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE",
  "com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"
],
```

Comment: thanks Muhammad, I'll attempt editing the AndroidManifest.xml manually later.

But I am already specifiying "permissions": []
Yet I'm getting more than the minimum permissions and Google is requesting a Privacy Policy because of those additional permissions.

Comment: sure, I just need to figure out how to edit the manifest of a app-bundle published from teh Expo flow without ejecting then will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: @Rich https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/941#issuecomment-405214705

Comment: @Rich for privacy policy https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3774#issuecomment-526516909

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar problem, but in my case I ejected from Expo workflow. However, the dependencies & permissions specified by Expo are still there. I can see permissions like android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on play console, even though the app doesn't need them. I have also removed all permissions except Internet from AndroidManifest.xml